# Google Analytics integration not working in an iOS App

Tags: ios, ios6, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am integrating Google analytics in an iOS App. I have a made a separate sample project and its working fine.
But when I am implementing the same in my App its not working.

- Are there any frameworks that will restrict the App for not running Google Analytics?

Comment: too less info. Update your question with some more (useful) information.

Comment: @Matt Tel me what info u require for that??

Answer (score 1):

First there are NO FRAMEWORKS that will restrict the app from running Google Analytics. But if you dont add certain frameworks you wont be able to compile the code.

Take a look at these links as these might be helpfull

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources

mainly this one which is below

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/

Apart from this if you are working on Google Analytics for the first time. Let me tell you that you will only find your data on the Google Analytics Dashboard after some time. It may also take a day if its the first time.So be patient if have been able to compile the code and run the app. After the first time its quick. i.e. the data shows up much faster.

Comment: Hey thanks.
I have followed these links and built my application.Statistics don't appear on my dashboard even after a couple of days now.

Comment: GAIDispatcher internalCreateTimer is not getting in my project where in the sample which i have made its showing this -[GAIDispatcher internalCreateTimer] (GAIDispatcher.m:195) DEBUG: Created timer to fire every 120.0s

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have been able to do Google Analytics (GA) working as expected.

The problem was not due to any framework incompatibility, neither project build settings, nor plist option. I recreated the same configuration into another project to be sure.

From my point of view, the first problem I had was to try using the GA SDK v3 within an Xcode v4.6.3 while Xcode v5 is expected.
Then Downgrading the GA SDK version to 2 beta4 has not directly solved the problem because perhaps GA SDK's persistent data was kept in my app (by user default or core data).

@BhargaviShamukh, if you still have this issue, the way to solve it should be to clean the project (menu Product > Clean) and to uninstall the app from both simulator and device to be sure any GA SDK's data is deleted.
At least for me, this process has solved the problem.